# How often does SQL Server refresh group policy?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, security

Does SQL Server check against the Windows GPO on the local server it is running on or with the domain controller?

Does SQL Server update the GPO at its own interval or immediately when the server has its GPOs applied? If it has its own interval, is there a specific refresh rate? I am having difficulty finding docs on this so I figured I would ask the community.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't really interact directly with a domain controller, or even read group policies directly.   That is all handled by Windows.

Comment: Hi David, understood - thanks. So SQL Server interacts with Windows , but how often does it interact? If a windows GPO were to be updated on the OS, how long would it take for SQL Server to notice and apply it?

Comment: I still don't understand. What sort of GP would SQL Server be responsible to "apply"?

Comment: Password policy (age, complexity) could be one for example. If password policy were updated on Windows level, it would also be applied on SQL server. so the question is how long would it take for SQL to realize the change if it has been applied on the OS?

Comment: There's no delay.  After you change the policy in Windows the next time you create a login SQL Server will enforce it.